# A question on K- theory of non commutative $C^\star$ algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

**Edit:** According to the comment of Andre Henriques I revise the question:

What is  an example  of  a  noncommutative unital $C^\star$  algebra $A$, which is not Morita equivalent to a  commutative algebra,  such that for  all unital subalgebra $B$ of  $A$, $ K_{0}(B)$  has $\mathbb{Z}$ as a summand? This  question is  motivated by [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169270/topological-k-theory-for-commutative-c-algebras) and the fact that  commutative  algebras and their  matrix algebras satisfies the  above  property.

Comment: Euhh... 2x2 matrices?

Comment: @AndréHenriques thank you for the comment. I revise my question.

Comment: Why would it be interesting if such an object existed? and why would it be interesting if no such objects existed?

Comment: @YemonChoi this  would be  a possible  characterization of commutative algebra in term of  $K$-theory, up to Morita equivalent.

Comment: Here's the simplest example of a $C^*$-algebra that isn't Morita equivalent to a commutative $C^*$-algebra: functions from $[0,1]$ to 2x2-matrices, that take diagonal values at $0$. I think that it already provides a counterexample to your "characterization of commutative algebras".

Comment: @AndréHenriques  could  you please more  explain that why  an interval with double ends is  a  counter example?May you explain in detail. Regarding your last statement I  do not remember this example as  an answer to my question. My  only characterization of  commutative  algebra is [the  following](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152984/characterization-of-commutative-banach-algebras).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question only requires regarding K$_0$ as an abelian group (it has a natural pre-ordering too), which makes it easy to construct simple (in the technical sense) examples.

Let $A$ be a simple infinite dimensional unital AF C*-algebra, whose K$_0$ group is free (as an abelian group) [*lots* of examples exist; see any  basic work on AF algebras]. If $B$ is a unital subalgebra, it is stably finite (as $A$ is stably finite). Hence the image of $K_0(B)$ in $K_0(A)$ is nonzero (actually, we knew this anyway, since the free module on one generator over $B$ has nonzero image in K$_0(A)$). The image of K$_0(B)$ is a nonzero subgroup of the free abelian group K$_0(A)$, so is itself free, and thus the map to its image splits. So $\bf Z$ is a direct summand of $K_0(B)$. [Even though $K_0(B) \to K_0(A)$ need not be one to one!]

And a simple infinite-dimensional C*-algebra is not Morita equivalent to a commutative one.

Comment: Prof. Handelman, Thank you very much for your very interesting answer.